# MONGODB | Address family not supported by protocol family - connect(2) for [::1]:27017

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `rails 5` and lastest `mongoid` gem, and when running `mongodb` server with any Model will throw this error:

```
MONGODB | Address family not supported by protocol family - connect(2) for [::1]:27017
```

I almost searched everything but I can't find any solution.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just ran into this myself when upgrading the `mongo` gem to `2.5.0` (from `2.4.3`). It looks like you can no longer connect to a Mongo instance using a domain name, in my case (and probably your's) `localhost`.

Change your `MONGOID_HOST` from `localhost:27017` to `127.0.0.1:27017`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've just saved my life. It really work.
Once again, thank you very very much!!!

Comment: Had same issue, thanks, they shouldn't make that of a breaking change in a minor version release.

Comment: This was hard to debug.. I only found the `Address family not supported by protocol family` error message by setting my logger like this:
`Mongo::Logger.logger = Logger.new($stdout, :debug)`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use resolve to convert the domain name to an IP address:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html

```
host = ARGV[0] # domain name passed in from cli
host = Resolv.getaddress host # resolve to first IP address
```